# Hide action column icon with getClass in Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have 3 icons in action columns,Edit,Delete,Publish for every rows in grid view.
Now what i want  is to hide the publish icon and change to unpublish icon on certain conditions.(My records are coming from mysql db).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example from my project.

Using getClass property of actioncolumn item to achieve this. To hide it return "x-hide-display" class name.

```
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
  items: [
      {
      getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
          // hide this action if row data flag indicates it is not deletable
          if(r.data.deletable == false) {
              return "x-hide-display";
          }
      },
      handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
          //do something
      },
      icon: 'icons/delete.png'
      }
  ]                             
]
```

Comment: for those who are using extjs5 "x-hide-display" has been changed to "x-hidden-display"

Answer (score 0):

I had to face similar situation but my requirement changed so, didn't get time to implement help some of people suggested.

You can check it out at

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149763-How-to-Change-action-column-icon-dynamically